# What does "upstream subscription" mean for a Combine Subject type?

Tags: swift, reactive-programming, combine

In [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/subject/3362858-send) for the [`Subject`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/subject) protocol of Apple's Combine framework there's this description for the `send(subscription: Subscription)` function:

> This call provides the `Subject` an opportunity to establish demand for any new upstream subscriptions.

There are similar [`send`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/subject/3213648-send) functions on `Subject` that allow publishing either an `Output` value or a `Void` value, but it's still isn't clear how would a `Subject` type use a subscription sent to it or what's the meaning of that.

The only two types conforming to `Subject` that Combine currently provides are [`CurrentValueSubject`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/currentvaluesubject) and [`PassthroughSubject`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/passthroughsubject), neither has any documentation for their `send(subscription: Subscription)` implementations.

What does it mean for a type conforming to `Subject` to have an "upstream subscription"? A downstream subscription for a `Subject` would be created for something that subscribes to this subject, but what would be the purpose of an upstream subscription here? Please provide real-world examples if possible.

Answer (score 1):

In both of `CurrentValueSubject` and `PassthroughSubject`, the objects exist to allow immediate code to have a handle to interact with and publish to a Combine publisher/async kind of mechanism. In doing so, these act at Publishers, which means they have to obey the rather strict lifecycle of a Combine publisher.

I have a [general overview of that lifecycle](https://heckj.github.io/swiftui-notes/#coreconcepts-lifecycle) within [Using Combine](https://gum.co/usingcombine) that you can scan for a quick overview. To answer your more specific question, a publisher is expected to *not* publish any values until a subscriber has connected and made a demand request.

The API that's exposed in Subject is `send()`, the general form of which is used to send values to subscribers if they've subscribed. 
When you're using a Subject of either form, you generally don't need to mess with the send for the subscriber, letting the general instances handle all the subscription and response mechanisms.

So you'd really only need to implement it if you were making your own object that was conforming to Subject - that is, making your own implementation of a Subject rather than building on one of the two variations Apple has already provided.

That particular method allows you to respond to subscription requests, allowing you to record and create notations (if needed) to handle demand allocation that comes along with the subscription. Each [subscription](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/subscription) that comes from subscribers connecting has some identity associated with it, and the built-in classes do all the tracking of subscribers and their `subscriptions` as they get created.

I personally find it much easier to build over one of the existing Subjects, composing it into whatever I need to publish updates.

Comment: Thanks! I think this explains what a downstream subscription for a subject is, but what is an "upstream subscription" in this context then?

Comment: An "upstream" subscription is a subscription that the Subject makes to anything when it's connected in a chain. When you're working with subjects, there's not usually a chained subscription like you'd see with an operator, Instead of a specific subscription, it's usually happening with more immediate calls to .send() to pass along data.

Even still, as a publisher itself the Subject has to be able to respond to subscriptions, which is the core of the method you were asking about.

Comment: And what's the difference between an upstream subscription and a downstream subscription then?

Comment: In reference to a subject, it's harder to define - for general "operators" within Combine (things which act as both a publisher and subscriber):
- upstream are the publishers which you subscribe to, and which provide published values upon demand requests
- downstream are the subscribers to which you publish, and which you provide values upon demand requests

Answer (score 0):

`send(subscription: )` method used in Publishers.Multicast.

Multicast will make pipeline like this.

```
[upstream: some Publisher]
 -> [Multicast]
 -> [Subject]
 -> [Subscriber: like Sink, Assign]
```

Subject must demand to `Multicast`'s upstream,
when any `Subscriber` demand some.

so `Subject` should know about upstream's subscription, when used with Multicast.

If just Single instance `Subject` for SomeValue Publishing like `@Published`, will not use this methods.
But if use with `Multicast`, will use this method.

see also

```
// operator
func multicast<S>(() -> S) -> Publishers.Multicast<Self, S>

// Publishers.Multicast
final class Multicast<Upstream, SubjectType>
where Upstream : Publisher,
    SubjectType : Subject, 
    Upstream.Failure == SubjectType.Failure,
    Upstream.Output == SubjectType.Output
```